# Bullet not always hitting Enemy

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col){

        if (col.gameObject.name == "Enemy1") {
                    enemyDamage++;

            GameObject clone = (GameObject) Instantiate (tempBloodSplat,enemyObj.position,enemyObj.rotation);
                    Destroy (clone , 0.5f);
            if (enemyDamage > 3) {

                anim.SetFloat ("Die", 0.5f);
                Destroy (enemyObj.gameObject , 5.0f);
            }
            Debug.Log ("Bullet is hitting Enemy");
        }
    }
```

This is my code, i used on BulletObject

1. My Bullet Object has Collider
2. My Enemy has a Collider
3. My Enemy has a Rigidbody
4. Bullet is not having Rigidbody

I have problem that when i shoot, the bullet is hitting the Enemy in his range, like the circle under the body of the Enemy,[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kmssp.jpg)

Sometimes the bullet hits correctly (means enemy is damaged), but sometimes the bullet moves out without making any damage to the enemy,I don't know why its happening.Does the velocity of the bullet has any effect on it..

Please help or guide me to solve this problem, Thanks

Comment: "Does the velocity of the bullet has any effect on it"? Yes it has try changing to continuous collision detection. You always can ask yourself if bullet is actually visible to player. If not try to do a raycast instead of moving actual object. Remember videogames are all about smoke and mirrors.

Comment: Btw, If object (bullet) in unity is moving you should add to it Rigidbody.

Comment: @Logman-  Bullet is following the Raycast path and finally hitting the Enemy, if i slow down the speed of the bullet, then also. it is not damaging the enemy, if i add rigidbody, the collision still not detecting with enemy.

Comment: Is this problem deterministic? If yes you can debug it frame by frame (button next to play). It's hard to tell what is wrong but problem could be in a way you move your bullet or object you shooting at. Did you change collision detection on rigidbody (on bullet and enemy) to continuous also try continuous dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not using a rigidbody on the bullet, then you are probably updating the bullets position vector directly, and what could be happening is the following:
[image]. Since the bullet is not a rigidbody, Unity does not 'assume' it should behave like one and thus does not do an actual physics simulation of the bullet movement (which would probably include a raycast from start position to end position and colision checking in between). If you have a problem with adding a rigidbody to the bullet, then do the raycast yourself. You will even learn a bit of how the physics simulation behind unity actually might work!

Good Luck!